# How long does the private beta last?

Tags: discussion, beta

At the time of this question, we're undergoing a private beta.

How long does this private beta last?

SE system requirements require me to elaborate on a short question.

Burma shave.

Comment: Just wanted to share this answer on [What is the Stack Exchange (Staff) process of launching a site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200383/210032). The answer by @JohnCavan is consistent with that answer there tho, so I'm linking that one from mSO in case others are interested in all the procedures involved with launching a new [se] site. A lot of interesting information in the answer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the email I got, the private beta lasts 1 to 2 weeks as the site scope gets formulated and there's an initial question base to guide newcomers.